# Create an dynamic array of buffers?

Tags: c

I'm trying to create an array of buffers.

I have a loop that does:

```
for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++){
    read(textFile, buffer, spacer);
    pthread_create(&myThread, NULL, processData, (void *)buffer);
}
```

The issue is that while the thread is running, the next iteration of the loop changes the buffer I'm assuming. And that makes the second loop not run correctly. Would I need to create an array? As in

```
char *array[threadCount]
```

And each index of that array is a buffer?

I'm not sure how I would allocate memory for that. If there's another obvious solution I'm missing, that would be great.

Comment: What does your declaration of `buffer` look like?

Comment: 1) Your strategy sounds reasonable.  2) I'd malloc() the buffer before I create the thread, then pass `(void *)buffarray[n]` to pthread_create(). 3) You might need to do "something extra" if it's important for your "main routine" to keep track of which thread is populating which buffer.

Comment: The reason @user3386109 asks, is because there are several ways to allocate the buffers you need (some combination of global or stack or heap arrays for outer or inner arrays), and knowing how you're allocating the current (single) buffer would allow people to suggest a similar strategy for allocating multiple buffers. Without knowing that, we might suggest something significantly different from your current setup. I'd suggest including a complete [MCVE] to forestall future questions.

Comment: char*buffer = (char*)malloc(spacer);

Comment: Ok, instead of calling `malloc` once, you need a loop that calls it `threadCount` times. The declaration `char *buffer[threadCount]` is correct, and you just pass `buffer[i]` to `pthread_create`. No need for a cast.

Comment: I added an answer that shows an alternative method of a single allocation to `create a dynamic array of buffers`, where the buffers are fixed in size (the example code rounds the buffers to 4 byte boundaries). The allocated memory will include an array of pointers to the buffers, followed by the buffers.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the same pointer to every thread. And you're repeatedly overwriting the memory to which that pointer points.

You have a similar problem with `myThread`. You place the thread id of every thread into the same variable.

You'll need an array of thread ids. For the buffer, you could create an array (as you mentioned) and pass the index. Or you could replace

```c
pthread_t myThread;
char buffer[spacer];
for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++){
   read(textFile, buffer, spacer);
   pthread_create(&myThread, NULL, processData, buffer);
}
```

with something like

```c
pthread_t myThreads[threadCount];
for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++){
   char *buffer = malloc(spacer);
   read(textFile, buffer, spacer);
   pthread_create(myThreads+i, NULL, processData, buffer);
}
```

(The thread is responsible for freeing the buffer.)

(Removed the useless cast.)

Comment: This worked, thank you. There should be no issues with relying on a thread to free memory? As long as I free the memory if the thread fails to create?

Comment: @code1331: Yeah, if the thread launches, and it's careful to `free` when it's done, no issues. If the process exits before the thread gets around to it, allocations are cleaned up on process exit anyway (`valgrind` and the like would complain, but if you're dying with still running threads, there's going to be a lot to complain about anyway).

Comment: @code1331, It's all the same process. It doesn't matter which thread allocates and which frees the memory, as long as it gets done exactly once. Yes, I would check if the thread successfully started. (I would also check that `read` and `malloc` succeeded...) And yeah, it would be the loop's job to free the memory if the thread doesn't start.

Answer (score 0):

Given you're using dynamic allocation, the correct solution would typically be to change:

```
char *buffer = malloc(spacer);
// Check for allocation error here
for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++){
    read(textFile, buffer, spacer);
    pthread_create(&myThread, NULL, processData, (void *)buffer);
}
// Wait for threads and maybe do something with buffer here
free(buffer);
```

to:

```
char **buffers = malloc(threadCount * sizeof(*buffers));
// Check for allocation error here
// Alternative if relying on VLA support is okay, or threadCount is a program constant
// char *buffers[threadCount];
// saves an allocation and for non-absurd thread counts shouldn't be too hard on the stack

for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++){
    buffers[i] = malloc(spacer);
    // Check for allocation error here
}
for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++){
    read(textFile, buffers[i], spacer);
    pthread_create(&myThread, NULL, processData, (void *)buffers[i]);
}
// Wait for threads and maybe do something with buffers here
for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++){
    free(buffers[i]);
}
free(buffers); // Omit if buffers itself was not malloc-ed above
```

If the main thread doesn't need to use the contents of the buffers after the threads are done processing, you can have the threads free their own buffer when they're done with it and save the work in the main thread (the main thread would only be responsible for freeing the top level `buffers` array).

Comment: It's possible to optimize further when the main thread will wait for and bulk `free` the allocations after all worker threads complete (performing a single bulk allocation and subdividing it, with a single bulk `free` at the end), but that's more complicated and harder to debug if you get it wrong (out-of-bounds reads/writes won't be error even if you're using valgrind or alternate allocators or the like to check for them, because the logical arrays would all be adjacent), so I'd suggest individual `malloc`s unless you can verify the fragmented allocation is actually a concern for performance.

Comment: A single allocation would make sense if this was multi-process program that needed to share memory, since only a single block of shared memory would be needed.

Answer (score -1):

Example with a single one time allocation for both the array of pointers to buffers and the buffers themselves (assumes all buffers are the same size). The buffers are rounded up to 4 byte boundaries. As mentioned in ShadowRanger's answer, a debugger wouldn't catch out of bounds indexing on each buffer with  this single allocation method. When running this program I had count set to 20 and buffer size set to 30 (it will be rounded up to 32). Buffer size just needs to be greater than zero (a size of 1 will get rounded up to 4) for the sprints().

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
char **arr;
char *bfr;
int cnt;
int siz;
int i;

    /* get and check parameters */
    if(argc != 3)
        return 0;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &cnt);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &siz);
    if(cnt <= 0 || cnt > 99 || siz <= 0 || siz > 1024)
        return  0;
    /* single allocation, buffers rounded to 4 byte boundaries */
    arr = malloc((cnt*sizeof(char *))+(cnt*4*((siz+3)/4)));
    if(arr == NULL)
        return 0;
    /* optional - zero memory */
    memset(arr, 0, (cnt*sizeof(char *))+(cnt*4*((siz+3)/4)));
    /* initialize array of pointers to buffers */
    for(i = 0, bfr = (char *)(arr+cnt); i < cnt; i++, bfr += 4*((siz+3)/4))
        arr[i] = bfr;
    /* write integer strings to buffers for display */
    for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        sprintf(arr[i], "%2d", i);
    /* display buffers */
    for(i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    /* free allocated memory */
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is totally incorrect.

Comment: This answer needs to identify the OP's problem and how the code helps to solve it.

Comment: @ikegami - this example code `creates a dynamic array of buffers` of fixed size (rounded to 4 byte boundaries). If the buffers are not fixed in size, RangerShadow's answer covers that case.

Comment: Now that's just an unreadable mess of code that doesn't compile cleanly and triggers sanitizers [link](https://godbolt.org/z/j1zE7YzE3).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. -  I updated my answer. Command line arguments used for buffer count and size now. [link](https://godbolt.org/z/1T6EP4ofo) .

Comment: The code is still a total untouchable mess.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. - so what would you change for a single allocation example (or maybe post an answer)?